# Learning how to create a video membership website in Python, but having trouble replacing Youtube videos with other video sites

Tags: python

I'm looking through the code and making a lot of bad assumptions. I'm attempting to change Youtube urls and verbage to other hosting platforms I'm also using for the future, Streamtape, Doodstream etc.

Trying to change some of the lingo caused the uvicorn server to crash

For example here's the model.py code

Anything changed from Youtube to either Streamtape or Doodstream causes
ImportError: cannot import name 'InvalidStreamtapeVideoURLException' from 'app.videos.exceptions'
or
ImportError: cannot import name 'InvalidDoodstreamVideoURLException' from 'app.videos.exceptions'

Trying to see what options to look into while learning and replacing websites to use.

```
import uuid
from app.config import get_settings
from app.users.exceptions import InvalidUserIDException
from app.users.models import User

from cassandra.cqlengine import columns
from cassandra.cqlengine.models import Model

settings = get_settings()

from .exceptions import (
    InvalidYouTubeVideoURLException, 
    VideoAlreadyAddedException
)
from .extractors import extract_video_id


# Unlisted Video -> video_id -> lock it down

class Video(Model):
    __keyspace__ = settings.keyspace
    host_id = columns.Text(primary_key=True) # YouTube, Vimeo
    db_id = columns.UUID(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid1) # UUID1
    host_service = columns.Text(default='youtube')
    url = columns.Text() # secure
    user_id = columns.UUID()
    # user_display_name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.__repr__()

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Video(host_id={self.host_id}, host_service={self.host_service})"

    def as_data(self):
        return {f"{self.host_service}_id": self.host_id}

    @staticmethod
    def add_video(url, user_id=None):
        # extract video_id from url
        # video_id = host_id
        # Service API - YouTube / Vimeo / etc
        host_id = extract_video_id(url)
        if host_id is None:
            raise InvalidYouTubeVideoURLException("Invalid YouTube Video URL")
        user_exists = User.check_exists(user_id)
        if user_exists is None:
            raise InvalidUserIDException("Invalid user_id")
        # user_obj = User.by_user_id(user_id)
        # user_obj.display_name
        q = Video.objects.allow_filtering().filter(host_id=host_id, user_id=user_id)
        if q.count() != 0:
            raise VideoAlreadyAddedException("Video already added")
        return Video.create(host_id=host_id, user_id=user_id, url=url)



# class PrivateVideo(Video):
# pass
```

and here's the schemas.py code

```
from pydantic import (
    BaseModel,
    validator,
    root_validator
)

from app.users.exceptions import InvalidUserIDException


from .exceptions import (
    InvalidYouTubeVideoURLException, 
    VideoAlreadyAddedException
)
from .extractors import extract_video_id
from .models import Video

class VideoCreateSchema(BaseModel):
    url: str # user generated
    user_id: str # request.session user_id

    @validator("url")
    def validate_youtube_url(cls, v, values, **kwargs):
        url = v
        video_id = extract_video_id(url)
        if video_id is None:
            raise ValueError(f"{url} is not a valid YouTube URL")
        return url

    @root_validator
    def validate_data(cls, values):
        url = values.get("url")
        user_id = values.get("user_id")
        video_obj = None
        try:
            video_obj = Video.add_video(url, user_id=user_id)
        except InvalidYouTubeVideoURLException:
            raise ValueError(f"{url} is not a valid YouTube URL")
        except VideoAlreadyAddedException:
            raise ValueError(f"{url} has already been added to your account.")
        except InvalidUserIDException:
            raise ValueError("There's a problem with your account, please try again.")
        except:
            raise ValueError("There's a problem with your account, please try again.")
        if video_obj is None:
            raise ValueError("There's a problem with your account, please try again.")
        if not isinstance(video_obj, Video):
            raise ValueError("There's a problem with your account, please try again.")
        return video_obj.as_data()
```